# Using CameraDevice and CameraSettings javacv

Tags: java, javacv

I don't know how this classes work. I am trying to know what cameras are available. Also, if possible, I would like to change settings of the camera (this I think I can figure it out by myself, but an example would be great).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get the camera list you can simply use

```
int n = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.videoInput.listDevices();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   String info = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.videoInput.getDeviceName(i);

   System.out.println(info);
}
```

you can get the image resolution by calling

```
grabber.getImageWidth();
grabber.getImageHeight();
```

also for set can use `setImageWidth()`, `setImageHeight()`

Comment: Thanks for that. Iis there a way to know supported resolutions?